# How to make ucwords ignore words in all caps?

Tags: php

I have some text that I need each first letter capitalized. But some words are in all caps and I want those words ignored.

```
$foo = 'product manufacturer for CAMERON TRAILERS';
$foo = ucwords($foo);
```

I need this to output as follows:

```
Product Manufacturer For CAMERON TRAILERS.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: i think ucwords works like that.

Comment: use ucwords(strtolower($foo));

Comment: Relevant/Handy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817754/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, since neither [`ucfirst`](http://www.php.net/ucfirst) nor [`ucwords`](http://www.php.net/ucwords) ever translates an uppercase character to its lowercase counterpart; `ucwords` should be fine for this case. I've changed the function below, so that it will make it *more normative* though, which would be necessary depending on how you interpret the question.

---

You'll need to define your own function to do this; PHP has no function with this behavior in its standard library (see note above).

```
// Let's create a function, so we can reuse the logic
function sentence_case($str){
    // Let's split our string into an array of words
    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach($words as &$word){
        // Let's check if the word is uppercase; if so, ignore it
        if($word == strtoupper($word)){
            continue;
        }
        // Otherwise, let's make the first character uppercase
        $word = ucfirst(strtolower($word));
    }
    // Join the individual words back into a string
    return implode(' ', $words);
}

echo sentence_case('product manufacturer for CAMERON TRAILERS');
// "Product Manufacturer For CAMERON TRAILERS"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I appreciate everyones help and patience.

Comment: The answer above, doesn't work if the sentence is Unicode.
I improved the answer as follows


`function sentence_case($str){
    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach($words as &$word){
        if($word == mb_convert_case($word, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8")){
            continue;
        }
       
    $word = mb_convert_case($word, MB_CASE_TITLE , "UTF-8");
    }
    return implode(' ', $words);
}

//echo sentence_case('tuyển nhân viên bán hàng trên sàn MTĐT');
// "Tuyển Nhân Viên Bán Hàng Trên Sàn MTĐT"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when you expect like this`Product Manufacturer For Cameron Trailers`

```
$foo = 'product manufacturer for CAMERON TRAILERS';
echo $foo = ucwords(strtolower($foo));
```

Look at here http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucwords.php. ucwords not transilating upperletter words

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucwords($foo);             // Hello World!

$bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
$bar = ucwords($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar)); // Hello World!
?>
```