# ucword() function with roman numerals

Tags: php

I am using ucword function to uppar case only first word as this `ucwords(strtolower($var))` but sometimes I want the word to be uppar case. Please see the below example to understand clearly.

```
$var = "class iii";
echo ucwords(strtolower($var));
gives as **Class Iii or Class Ii or Class Iv**
```

What I want it should display as **`Class III or Class II or Class IV`** to look beautiful

Comment: Relevant/Handy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817754/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
<?php

    function xucwords($string)
    {
        $words = split(" ", $string);
        $newString = array();

        foreach ($words as $word)
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^m{0,4}(cm|cd|d?c{0,3})(xc|xl|l?x{0,3})(ix|iv|v?i{0,3})$/", $word)) {
                $word = ucfirst($word);
            } else {
                $word = strtoupper($word);
            }
            
            array_push($newString, $word);
        }
        
        return join(" ", $newString);  
    }
    
    echo xucwords('class iii');
    
?>
```

based on the function found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.strtolower.php#28660).

Comment: If you are copying from the source http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/function.strtolower.php.htm , you need to specify the link !

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I did.

Comment: could you please tell me what is in $lower_exceptions array ??

Comment: @user3477550 It is just to keep those list of words lower case. Like `a` or `the` will always be lower case.

Comment: @user3477550 I modified the code and removed the lower_exceptions.

Comment: Hi Majimboo, I tried this but the resule is same as ucword. `echo xucwords("class iii");
echo xucwords("class iv");
echo xucwords("class bla bla iii");
echo xucwords("final exam iii");` gives me `Class IiiClass IvClass Bla Bla IiiFinal Exam Iii `

Comment: Thank you very much dear, Its working perfect... I appreciate your hard work.

Comment: @majimboo: I noticed that you removed the credits a few minutes ago. Always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text/code, including a direct link to it. Plagiarism isn't welcome on Stack Overflow (or on any SE site for that matter).

Comment: @AmalMurali sorry about that. I was just editing my answer. Also there is now a difference between the code on the site and the code i posted. But anyways, noted.

Comment: Change the `$words = split(" ", $string);` to `$words = split(" ", strtolower($string));`. Because if string is class Iii or class III will not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) with a regex that uses positive lookahead:

```
/\b(?=[LXIVCDM]+\b)([a-z]+)\b/i
```

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - assert position at a word boundary
- `(?=` - positive lookahead

  - `[LXIVCDM]+` - match any character from the list one or more times
  - `\b` - assert position at a word boundary
- `)` - end of positive lookahead
- `[a-z]` - any alphabet
- `\b` - assert position at a word boundary
- `i` - pattern modifier that makes the matching case-insensitive

**Code:**

```
$str = "class iii";

$string = preg_replace_callback('/\b(?=[LXIVCDM]+\b)([a-z]+)\b/i', 
function($matches) {
    return strtoupper($matches[0]);
}, ucwords(strtolower($str)));

echo $string;
```

**Output:**

```
Class III
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137318)

Comment: Sorry its showing same Parse error: syntax error in T_FUNCTION but I saw in demo its working. I tested in my live website.. twice

Comment: @user3477550: In that case, you're probably using an older version of PHP. **Upgrade**. If you can't, use this instead: https://eval.in/137326

Comment: @user3477550: Did you see my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

You the below code and see my inline comments

```
$var = "class iii";

echo upperCaseCustomFunction($var);

upperCaseCustomFunction($string) {

    $arr = explode(" ",$string);

    $stringPartOne = ucwords(strtolower($arr[0])); // will return Class 

    $stringPartTwo = strtoupper(strtolower($arr[1]));   // Will return III 

    return $tringPartOne." ".$stringPartTwo; // will return Class III

}
```

Comment: Dear, its just a example I have given, I, II, III its not always come on the $arr[1] position. Like Mid Exam III or Mid Exam IV

Answer (score 0):

`ucwords` will convert only first character of string in uppercase.

You have to find for all iii or iv first convert it to uppercase and then apply ucowrds to whole string.

Answer (score -1):

Simple use like below :

```
$var = strtolower("class ") . strtoupper("iii");
echo ucwords($var);
```

//Gives Class III

Comment: for how many varibles I have to write this line. I jsut gave the example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
$var = "class iii";
$var =  ucfirst(strtolower($var));
echo str_replace(substr($var, 6), strtoupper(substr($var, 6)), $var);
?>
```

Output:

```
Class III
```